# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following columns in my table:

```
year  decimal(4,0)
month decimal(2,0)
day   decimal(2,0)
```

and I am trying to convert them as below:

```
SELECT (CAST (CAST(year  AS varchar(4))
             +CAST(month AS varchar(2))
             +CAST(day   AS varchar(2)
             ) AS date ) ) AS xDate
FROM table 
ORDER BY xDate DESC
```

But I am getting this error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Are you trying to convert TO a datetime?

Comment: I did a quick test with hardcoded numbers, and it works for me, so are you sure "year", "month", and "date" are numbers and within acceptable range?

Comment: @Kris - I am trying to convert it to Date, but if it is easy to convert to datetime then that is also fine but i am getting error.

Comment: @jimo3 - Yes they are number but the datatype is decimal and trying to convert to Date datatype.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach does not take into account that `month` or `day` can be a single-digit value. If you had a row like this:

```
year  month  day
----  -----  ---
2014  7      18
```

your method would concatenate the parts as `2014718` and the subsequent attempt to convert that into a `date` would result in the error in question.

You probably meant to combine the parts like this: `20140718`, which would convert to `date` without issues. To me, the easiest way to get to that format from numerical parts is to go like this:

- calculate `year * 10000 + month * 100 + day`;
- convert the previous result to `char(8)`;
- convert the string to `date`.

So, in Transact-SQL it would be like this:

```
CAST(CAST(year * 10000 + month * 100 + day AS char(8)) AS date)
```

On a different note, I cannot possibly know whether you really need to store your dates split like that, of course, but if you do insist on doing so, at least consider using integer type(s) for the parts. I realise that `decimal(2,0)` may serve as some kind of constraint for you that makes sure that you cannot have month or day values with more than 2 digits, but it still does not protect you from having invalid months or days. And another major point is `decimal(2,0)` requires more storage space than even `int`, let alone `smallint` or `tinyint`.

So, this would seem fine to me

```
year  int,
month int,
day   int
```

but if you are into saving the storage space as much as possible, you could also try this:

```
year  smallint,
month tinyint,
day   tinyint
```

Finally, to make sure you cannot have invalid values in those columns, you could add a check constraint like below:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename
ADD CONSTRAINT CK_tablename_yearmonthday CHECK 
  ISDATE(CAST(year * 10000 + month * 100 + day AS char(8))) = 1
;
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is because you have redundant data in your table(Nothing wrong with your query). check following in your table.

1). values for **days columns** must not be greater than max number of days in **associated month** (e.g month 2 must not have 30 or 31 days in it).

2). value for **month column** must not be greater than **12** or equal to **0**.